# Как узнать количество вычислительных ядер GPU с помощью команды OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, nvidia

Как узнать количество вычислительных ядер GPU с помощью команды OpenGL не прибегая к использованию других api? Это мне необходимо, чтобы программа могла работать на любых компьютерах с любыми вариантами Nvidia GPU.

Comment: почему в противном случае она не будет работать на этих компьютерах? вычислительная нагрузка на GPU распределяется по ядрам автоматически

Comment: @user7860670 А как тогда настроить вычислительный шейдер OpenGL? Ведь у каждой карты свое количество ядер. И как использовать все ядра GPU в  вычислительном шейдере OpenGL? как обойти ограничение GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS если в GPU большее количество ядер чем GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_INVOCATIONS?